# Have a single running process in a 4 node Windows Server cluster

Tags: cluster, windows-server-2022

Is there a way to have a single running process in a 4 node setup on Windows Server?

And if the node running the process goes off, to automatically start it on one of the remaining 3 nodes?
Currently this has to be done without Docker, it has to be done on the VM level.

The 4 nodes would be running Windows Services, among them would be this one service. The services would be running on all 4 nodes simultaneously except this one service which I would like to run on a single node at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Generic Service can be made highly availably (HA) with Failover Cluster. The following article covers the configuration process: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/creating-and-configuring-a-generic-service-resource/ba-p/371443

As another option, you can configure your service to run inside of the VM and configure Hyper-V Failover cluster. It would be easier to manage and you will have your services running in isolated (separate environments).
Both option will require shared storage. It could be either a file share, SAN or a vSAN. As an example, you can use S2D or StarWind VSAN as a shared storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/storage-spaces-direct-overview

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

Answer (score -1):

Just so I get this right, you're not talking about trying to run a single process across four separate servers? (we do get that question every so often, it can kind of be done for some workloads but isn't always the right answer) - you're asking if you can have one VM running on a server but in the event of that server failing the VM will be restarted on one of the three remaining servers - is that right? If so then VMware's HA (High Availability) does exactly that. Obviously you need to have a VMware setup with four licenced copies of ESXi, a licenced vCenter and some form of shared storage (or vSAN) -  but it works, we have lots of this kind of setup and it definitely works.

I'm not sure if MS have an equivalent, certainly they can do that with some of their products, MS SQL can do that, file services (SMB) can do that, I think Exchange, maybe Sharepoint, can do that too - but in all those cases it's the application that's written to take advantage of clustering - it's not just a regular bit of software that magically can take advantage of that clustering. I also don't know if MS's HyperV hypervisor has the same 'HA' functionality I'm sorry, VMware have a LOT of patented functionality that they keep for their own products, meaning a lot of other hypervisors miss out on these functions, or have to do them in a very different, often poorer, way.

Maybe come back to us with a bit more detail and we could help more, hope this has been of use.

Comment: I've added more detail

Comment: Thanks for that, so will this 'solo' service be written to make use of MS Cluster Services?

Comment: I'm not sure, this I haven't done yet. I'm using MS Cluster Failover currently with one active node (with failover to inactive in case of problems), and would like to migrate the application to 4 active nodes setup. My point of view is from a developer perspective.